# Limiting the number of drop-down options

Tags: magento2, collection, dropdown-attribute

I have created an attribute which consists of two option. say A and B and on the front-end, I have another attribute which is a drop-down. Is it possible to limit the number of options in the front-end drop-down attribute based on another product attribute

Back-end
[image]

Front-end[image]

Actually limiting the configurable product which is shown in the front-end based on an attribute option

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance